# What is the meaning of parentheses around a SQL expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was just reading the docs for partial indexes in Postgres [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/indexes-partial.html). The very last code snippet:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tests_target_one_null ON tests ((target IS NULL)) WHERE target IS NULL;
```

contains some syntax I'm unfamiliar with. In particular it's the `(target IS NULL)` part. What are the inner parentheses doing here? Usually the syntax of a partial index create command is like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <index_name> ON <table_name>(<column_name>) WHERE <boolean_expression>;
```

Note: I *think* that's what the usual syntax is, but I am trying to learn from those docs and they are explaining-by-example, so I may be missing some subtlety here.

Anyway, if this is the case then it seems like `(target IS NULL)` somehow defines a column. Does the `( . )` operator define an anonymous function which is interpreted as a column here?

I'm quite new to SQL, and this is proving hard to google. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating indexes in PostgreSQL each section can be either a *column*, or an *expression*. They are, however, typed differently:

- To include a column just type its name, as in `col1`.
- To include an expression type it in between parenthesis, as in `(-col3 * 123)`.

For example, the following indexes are valid in PostgreSQL:

- `(col1, col2, col3)` -- three plain columns.
- `(col1, (-col2), col3)` -- two columns and one expression.
- `(col1, (col2 + col3))` -- one column and one expression.

The case you mention `target IS NULL` is an expression, so it must be typed in parenthesis, as in:

```
create index idx1 on my_table ((target IS NULL));
```

As for the "partial index" syntax, that is correct. You add the extra section `WHERE <predicate>` at the end. That tells PostgreSQL that only rows that match this predicate are included in the index. The rest won't populate the index.

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination!